# How to get input with a custom dictation command

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm trying to write a few scripts to allow me to write code via voice. However, I need a way to specify a way to capitalize a variable name. For example, I want to be able to say, "stud my super awesome variable" and have it send the keystrokes "mySuperAwesomeVariable".

I understand that custom dictation commands do not receive input. However, I need a way to at least simulate it.

I tried using the "Ask for Text" and "Run Applescript" actions with the following Applescript:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke input
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

But the problem is that I have manually give the "Ask for Text" popup focus. Any ideas what I could do instead?